# How to retrieve data attribute from selected datalist entry when multiple entries share same value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a datalist that users can select from like this:

```
<input list="user_names" id="names" name="user_name" />
<datalist id="user_names">
 <option value="bob" data_id="bob_10">10</option>
 <option value="bob" data_id="bob_5">5</option>
 <option value="james" data_id="james_7>7</option>
</datalist>
```

I have a hidden input field to hold the data attribute named "data_id":

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="" />
```

I'm using jQuery to populate the data_id value from what the user selects.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('#names').on('input, function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  var user_id = $('#user_names [value="' + value + '"]').data('id');
  document.getElementById('user_id').value = user_id;
 })
});
```

This works fine, except when two datalist options share the same value but not the same data-id (demonstrated with the two "bob" entries), jQuery picks the data-id of the first option instead of the one that was selected. Is there a way I could further filter what jQuery selects maybe by the text associated with each option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A basic idea of how a datalist works**

1. The datalist populates any input that refers to it.
2. Selecting an option from the list transfers **only the value attribute** to the input box.

**Your dilemma**

You can use the new value of the input element to search the datalist where it came from and recover any data stored there. When this technique is used that means you are using the value from the input to search the datalist.

If there are multiple items with the same value, you won't be able to know which one you want. Thus your dilemma.

**Conclusion**

At the moment there is no way to get around this. So you're going to have to be using unique values in your datalist. If you think about it there isn't any reason why you would make an user choose between identical values anyway.

**Sources**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

*PS: On a sidenote: You might not want to use text inside the option element or the label property. It seems different browsers treat them different. Leading to inconsistencies across browsers. Hopefully that will get sorted out in the years to come.*

Comment: Thanks for the response! I kind of knew that was the case, I was just hoping there might have been something out there that I missed. I just discovered the inconsistencies in the datalist element recently, and it's a big pain. I may end up using http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ instead. It looks like it can solve my problems!